# Structuring loop using csv and functions

Tags: python-2.7, loops, csv

I am having a problem with a loop within a loop.
I would like that for every featureclass(FC) the script should loop through "checklist" and where it is a match run the function findfield.
Currently the script seems to work for the first featureclass, iterating through the checklist, but then it just lists the remaining featureclasses without checking checklist..any ideas? suggestions

Thank you in advance

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
import os
import traceback
from arcpy import env
import csv
import sys

#Workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = "SchemaOnly.gdb"

usecsv = open(r'C:\Temp\GV\Final working\Domain and length out.csv','r') #open file
checklist = csv.reader(usecsv) #init csv reader

# function to change schema of featureclass
def FindField(fc,myField):
    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

    for field in fieldList:
        if str.lower(str(field.name)) == str.lower(myField):
            arcpy.AlterField_management(fc, myField, "", "", "text", new_length, "", "")
            print "    " + fc + " contains fieldname: " + myField



#Search Feature Datasets
for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature'):
    print "Searching FeatureDataset: " + fds

    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
        print "  Searching Featureclass... " + fc
        for row in checklist:
            #print row[0] #prints fieldname
            #print row[1] #prints newlength
            myField = row[0]
            new_length=row[1]
            FindField(fc,myField)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I managed to identify my own fix. The problem seemed to be when I wanted to iterate through checklist, it worked once in the nested loop but not again.
 The solution was to append checklist into a new list(fieldInfo) and then iterate through that list. Code changes below

```
checklist = csv.reader(usecsv) #init csv reader
fieldInfo = []
for row in checklist:
    fieldInfo.append([row[0],row[1]])
```